# railsでwebpacker:installした際のエラーについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

現在開発環境をdocker-composeにて自作したアプリを公開しようとしているのですが、`docker-compose up` をして "no such file please webpacker:install" と言われたので `rails webpacker:install` とすると以下のエラーが出ました。

```
Rails couldn't infer whether you are using multiple databases from your database.yml and can't generate the tasks for the non-primary databases. If you'd like to use this feature, please simplify your ERB.
Rails couldn't infer whether you are using multiple databases from your database.yml and can't generate the tasks for the non-primary databases. If you'd like to use this feature, please simplify your ERB.
rails aborted!
Cannot load database configuration:
YAML syntax error occurred while parsing /Users/hiratashinichi/rails/config/database.yml. Please note that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not allowed. Error: (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 18 column 3
```

自分が調べてやってみたことはdatabase.ymlの中のインデントを揃えたりしてみましたが同じエラーで変わりませんでした。
他に調べて気になったことはymlの中をスペースからタブに変換するみたいなことが記載されていたのでどなたかこちらのエラーに関することで分かる方がいましたら教えて頂けないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

エラーを読むと、`config/database.yml`のインデントにタブが使われているのが問題のようです。YAMLでは、タブによるインデントは許されないようです。
　18行目の3カラム目がタブのようなので、スペースで置き換えてみてください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ちなみにdatabase.ymlのpasswordはそのままyml内に記述すればよろしいのでしょうか？rails sをするとdatabaseがないと言われてdb:createをすると今度はパスワードがないと言われまして

Comment: database.ymlをgitなどで管理しなければならない（Herokuなどにデプロイする予定があるなど）場合は、環境変数で渡すようにしないとリポジトリにパスワードが含まれてしまって問題になります。そうでないなら、database.ymlを.gitignoreに登録して管理外にし、設置環境で手動でファイルを置くようにするなどすれば、直接記述しても構わないと思います。